# Troubles with deleting files from GitLab Master and Local (Student)

Tags: gitlab

I am currently doing an end of year project and we're using GitLab. This is the first time I am using this and was confident about it until the following problem occurred.

After creating the clone, I've been working on my project and committed quite a few files to the school server by using `git push` after doing the prerequisites of `git add` and etc.

Now, I've decided to completely start again. I deleted everything manually from GitLab and then all the files from within the folder where the clone directs to. I started working on my new work in a separate folder - while still working on my new file, I decided to move all the files to the previous file where I deleted everything, where the clone was originally set for GitLab to save my files within the schools server.

When typing `git status`, the following appears (Please excuse the picture instead of me inserting the code in here. I tried entering the output on the console in here but was having editing problems).
[image]

I don't understand how to fully delete everything. So, I want to get rid of all `Changes to be committed:` and `Untracked files:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **push** there nothing to do with **git status** . **git status** only shows what been added to your repository before commit.

Comment: Ok thank you. That makes sense. Not sure why I was getting very confused about that. Last question. I have used the command `git commit -m "Deleting everything"` and `git push`. Everything under `Changes to be committed` has been deleted. However, how do I delete everything under `Untracked files:`?

I appreciate all your help.